# unregister onSignalStrengthsChanged android

Tags: android

I am using

```
class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
        {
          @Override
          public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
          {
             super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
             Logger.debug("Signal:"+String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()));
          }
        };

        TelephonyManager        Tel;
        MyPhoneStateListener    MyListener;
        MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
        Tel       = ( TelephonyManager )c.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

for get current signal strengths.

But I want to know how to get current signal strength using this.
I don't want to get continuously signal updation..
Please give me some guide line to get signal strength on any particular event not continous

Answer (score 2):

After you get all needed data you can disable listener

```
Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```